# Update Bluetooth status on a switch in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

Im starting at Android Apps programing on Android Studio and im practicing on a simple bluetooth turn on/off switch, switch works fine it activates and deactivate the bluetooth, but if i activate or deactivate bluetooth from quick settings on the status bar(without closing the app) the switch doesnt update. I think the app lose the focus so i tried to verify the bluetooth status and update the switch on the onResume but it doesnt work. Some ideas?

```
public class bluetooth_Control extends AppCompatActivity{

    Switch aSwitch;
    BluetoothAdapter blueadp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bluetooth__control);

        aSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
        blueadp =   BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();



        aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(isChecked){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                }
                else{

                    blueadp.disable();
                }
            }
        });

    }



    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        setBTswitch(blueadp);
    }


    public void setBTswitch(BluetoothAdapter b){
        if(b.isEnabled()){
            aSwitch.setChecked(true);
        }
        else{
            aSwitch.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the code about "update the switch on the onResume()", otherwise we can't figure out what's wrong. I suggest adding logs in onResume() callback to check if codes getting the bluetooth status works fine.

Comment: Is there, the setBTswitch method check adapter status and set the switch checked if adapter is enable or unchecked if not

Comment: @tatteredPrince Sorry didn't scroll down to check. Like mentioned above, try adding logs to narrow things down like:


Then you can figure out wether not getting bluetooth status correctly or unable to set checked status of Switch.

Comment: @tatteredPrince Sorry didn't scroll down to check. Like mentioned above, try adding logs to narrow things down like in setBTswitch():
boolean isEnabled = b.isEnabled();
Log.d("my_tag", "is bluetooth enabled: " + isEnabled?"yes":"no");

Then you can figure out wether not getting bluetooth status correctly or unable to set checked status of Switch.

Comment: Thanks, check it with logs and the method works fine, even if i change the orientation of the device the switch updates. So my question is what hapens with the activity when the quick settings overlays it? is it on pause? or it is like nothing hapens?

Answer (score 0):

Ok if someone have the same restlessness i will only say: onWindowFocusChanged() because onResume() and onPause() doesnt triger when you drag down the notification and quick settings panel. That solve the problem, maybe it doesnt looks clean and accurate because the switch updates before you drag up to hide the notification and quick settings panel, i have been doing a little more research and maybe will be more accurate whith tiles listeners.